# Не подключается MockMvc

Tags: java, spring, mockito

Собираюсь тестить рест контроллер, но в который раз сталкиваюсь с проблемой подключения зависимостей. До этого не хотел подключать SpringRunner, сейчас же MockMvc. Сама зависимость в pom.xml прописана на подключение spring-test 5.2.0.RELEASE.

.m2/repository удалял
Пытался подключить spring-boot-test
Переоткрыть проект

Есть догадка, что дело в Idea, но без понятия в чем конкретно проблема

pom.xml

```html
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-test-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, нужно было сделать папку src/test/java/ и обозначить ее в project structure как папку с тестами (станет зеленой). Перенес тесты туда и все заработало